# Cannot alter SQL Server login using PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to alter a SQL Server login using PowerShell as administrator.

This is my script:

```
$query = @"
ALTER LOGIN [$SAUser] WITH PASSWORD='$SAUserPassword', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO
ALTER LOGIN [$SAUser] ENABLE
GO
"@ 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query -ServerInstance "$domain"
```

I get this error:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Verify that the target user exists on the SQL Server and that your own account has access to update its password and enable it.

Comment: Are you trying to modify an SQL Server Login (one that normally uses a Username and Password to connect), or a Windows/AD login (one that uses trusted authentication)? You can only change the password on an SQL Server Login.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Based on partially redacted login name, looks to be a SQL Authentication login, @AlwaysLearning , unless the OP is omitting the domain name and assuming that they can `ALTER` such a `LOGIN` without it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning yes its sql server login i am trying to setup